# Расстановка позиций с расстоянием

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть планета построенная из шестиугольных тайлов, последовательность которых хранится как одномерный массив a[n].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача выбрать список рандомных тайлов, удалённых друг от друга на расстояние не менее заданного расстояния X, ну или так чтобы они оказались рандомно расположены по миру, но не слишком близко друг к другу, для того чтобы поставить там поселения.

Из общего списка тайлов, используя linq я выбираю те что мне подходят (те которые не вода), с этим списком пытаюсь работать...

Пробовал рандомно расставлять каждый, проверяя расстояния между ним и всеми остальными уже отмеченными, но такой подход мне кажется костылем, да и при большом количестве время на это дело может быть очень не маленьким.

Ещё пробовал генерировать точки шумом, а после перебирать каждый на расстояние ко всем оставшимся кроме уже вошедших. Но такой подход хоть и немного легче, но все ещё какой то костыль.

Подскажите, какие ещё могут быть решения

Comment: линк слишком медленный для такой задачи. Линк я бы откинул изначально. Только для тестировки подхода и не более того.

Comment: Перебрать циклом перезаписывая нужные в List будет быстрее?

Comment: Линк в видеоиграх использовать желательно по-минимуму и только на легковесных задачах. В остальных случаях всякие циклы и ручная обработка данных окажутся значительно более быстрыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно конечно дать хексагоном свойство широты и долготы и иметь возможность считать расстояние между ними на сфере, но в поиске путей это не сильно поможет, да и считать расстояние между всеми, перебирая все элементы затратное дело.

Тут нужен граф. Добавь информацию о соседних хексагонах, их индексах
`int[] neighborings;`.

У хексагона есть тип, сделав таблицу проходимостей для разных типов, позволит строить пути не самыми короткими, а самыми быстрыми, не пытаясь идти по воде с коэффициентом
0 и обходя горы, болота и леса с низким коэффициентом при возможности, как на карте `RimWorld`.

Используя граф, можно искать хексагоны не только волновым способом, но и поиск пути A*.

Comment: Ну да, для поиска пути у меня уже есть параметр проходимости и индексы соседей и тд, и сам поиск пути в процессе разработки, но как мне поможет это расставить поселения? О, точно, может разобрать римворлд и глянуть как там хех)

Comment: Тыкаешь в случайный хексагон, проверяешь на валидность, новое поселение, тыкаешь в следующий и считаешь расстояния с предыдущими... вот и все. Проблема то в чем? Пиши алгоритм A* для измерения расстояний, как пеших с фактором скорости, так и просто по количеству тайлов. Ответ в сомом вопросе: " удалённых друг от друга", измерение расстояния это единственный необходимый инструмент.